# What is the purpose of the following inverter topology?

Tags: oscillator, schmitt-trigger

I stumbled upon an Schmitt-trigger oscillator circuit. I can fully understand the principles and its function, but what I cannot fully understand is the chain of inverters after it.

[image: The circuit including the Schmitt-trigger oscillator and the inverter chain after it]

In the above circuit I can understand the functionality of the first two inverters (for regenerative purposes/making the oscillation more "clear") but what is the purpose of the rest of the circuit, and especially of the 6th and the 7th inverter?

**EDIT**

This is the original image (it is not that detailed, but I hope you can extract some more useful info)

[image]

Comment: I guess you cannot show the original

Comment: try this  http://tinyurl.com/y2op5fnj

Comment: I can't see something, just a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

It somewhat depends on how the specific implementation technology deals with paralleled outputs, but my guess would be that this is supposed to generate a pair of nonoverlapping clock phases, commonly used in systems built using dynamic logic.

The idea is that only one of the outputs is high at a time, with no overlap during the transitions:

```
       ___________               _
______/           \_____________/
_____               ___________
     \_____________/           \__
```

Note how each output goes low *before* the other output goes high.

You can get the same effect (without the output conflicts) with a pair of cross-coupled NOR gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0iqok.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you switch to NAND gates, you get clocks that don't overlap in the low state.

Comment: I think I can kind of understand what you're saying, but it's not crystal clear to me. Could you please elaborate? For example, why is that important to generate this pair of non-overlapping transitions (and phases)? FYI this could be followed by a frequency divider (like a Johnson counter).

Comment: This circuit works well to truncate the trailing edge of Phase 1 going low. from prop delay of INV but not the leading edge of Phase 1 nor the trailing edge of Phase2, so there is a still potential race

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75: No, there isn't. Run the simulation and see for yourself.

Comment: I did, http://tinyurl.com/yxnl8nx6  you can see for yourself with slew rate limited inverters 0.5V/ns   I meant overlapping edges on one and not the other.

Comment: This http://tinyurl.com/y47adhyt

Comment: But OPs circuit has the NOT6 input and NOT7 outputs connected, and vise-versa. I can't think of any way NOT6 and 7 do anything the way they're connected.